# Make request after Vercel deployment

Tags: javascript, node.js, continuous-integration, vercel, cd

I need to make a request to third-party api in order to add new deployment url to whitelist. I need to make request (or run nodejs sript) after Vercel deploy my app. I read their docs but didn't find a way how to make smth after deployment.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can actually make it while you are building the app: https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/environment-variables
Search for `VERCEL_URL`